# Differentiating an infinite series in Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Suppose $H$ is separable Hilbert space and $w_j$ is a basis. Suppose we have $h=\sum a_j(t)w_j$ an infinite sum where the coefficients are functions of $t$. The sum makes sense in the sense that the partial sums converge to $h$. When are we allowed to differentiate term by term and write $h'=\sum a_j'(t)w_j$?

Also, how about if the basis functions depended on $t$ too?

Comment: There is no difference between Hilbert space-valued (or even Banach space-valued) functions and scalar-valued functions. So the basic criterion is the following: if the series of derivatives is uniformly convergent on compact sets, then you are allowed to differentiate term by term.